# onPause() & onSaveInstanceState() for created UI

Tags: android

First off I have searched for this info for about a week and found very little. So hopefully this long read helps some other new people.

I have created a `UI` from `JSON`. This `UI` has all kinds of `Views`. Such as `EditText`, `RadioButton`, `CheckBox`, `Spinner`, etc. Now I need to account for certain inevitable scenarios. Screen rotation, phone call, back button, home button etc. Since all these `Views` are created after a network call/response and this takes time I do not want to repeat this action each time. So saving the actual `RadioButton` or `EditText` and what was selected on the `RadioButton` or typed into the `EditText` is extremely important. From what I've read for screen rotation I use `onSaveInstanceState()`. For anything else I would use `onPause()` because it is the only thing that is garunteed to be called.

The problem is I have no idea how to store programatically created `Views` with **no id's** in `sharedprefs` or a `bundle` let alone the values they hold. Lets look at my code and then discuss what I think is currently possible.

```
    allEdit = new ArrayList<EditText>();

    else if (map.get(TAG_FIELD).equals(et)) {
                Log.v("RESPONSE", "About to create an EditText");
                // find
                LinearLayout content = (LinearLayout) getActivity()
                        .findViewById(R.id.add);
                // create
                TextView tv = new TextView(getActivity());
                EditText et = new EditText(getActivity());
                LinearLayout ll1 = new LinearLayout(getActivity());
                // set
                tv.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
                    et.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
                    ll1.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
                    tv.setText(map.get(TAG_NAME));
                    ll1.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
                    // add
                    ll1.addView(tv);
                    ll1.addView(et);
                    allEdit.add(et);
                    content.addView(ll1);
                }
```

So in the example above I have created an `EditText` and stored it in an `ArrayList<EditText>`. Now my thought is that in `onPause()` I could do something like this.

```
for (int i = 0; i < allEdit.size(); i++) {
    EditText et = allEdit.get(i);
    String input = et.getText().toString();
    prefsEdit.put(input);
}
```

Which I think might work, it also might overwrite the `String` "input" inside shared preferences over and over again. Not totally sure how that works. It also still does not solve how to save the actual `EditText` so that it does not have to be recreated.

Now in `onSavedInstanceState()` I think I may be able to get away with just inserting the whole `ArrayList<EditText>` as serializable, right? Like this...

```
putSerializable("key", allEdit)
```

However that does not save the values inside them.

So how do I save these `Views` **and** their values in `onSavedInstanceState()` and `onPause()`? Perhaps more importantly, do I need both? Can I get away with just using `onPause()`?

Thank you

Comment: check this link might help http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html

Comment: @Raghunandan I read the article. It touches on what I bring up here about not making network requests twice but it does not go over how to implement them on programatically created Views/Objects

Comment: @Raghunandan upon further review I found this setRetainInstance(). Which looks promising.

Comment: when orientation changes activity is recreated. so you need to only restore values to the views rather than the views itself

Comment: @Raghunandan well my code is inside a `fragment`. When my screen orientation changes it goes back 3 screens or `fragments` back to the parent `Activity`. This completely wipes out the created ui for the `fragment`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I havent tried this, but it sounds like it would work in practice. When creating the activity (before the JSON populates) create your own ViewGroup. From there, read the JSON and add every view that you get to the VeiwGroup. Then, when you want to save the information or whatever do this

```
int viewCount =  mViewGroup.getChildCount();
for(i=0;i<viewCount;i++) {
    newView = mViewGroup.getChildAt(i);
    if (newView instanceOf EditText) {
        EditText newEditText = (EditText)newView
        string value = newEditText.getText();
    } 
    else if (newView instanceOf RadioButton) {
         same as above ^
         etc...
    }

}
```

Then, for each of the values you pull add them to an array, maybe even a NamedPair to store their ID and value (by ID I mean index of which view it is). So

```
public List<String> lstEditTextValues = new ArrayList<String>();
```

After all that is said and done, then you can itterate through each one, and save it as an individual value through the bundle, save in a shared pref, or put into a static class level variable (not the safest way to retain information, but does work).

Hope this helps. Let me know if im completely off topic

Comment: I don't think you're off topic. I am just fairly new so this is somewhat confusing. So you're saying do away with my `ArrayList<EditText>` etc and add these `Views` to a `ViewGroup` instead? Then when I call `onSavedInstanceState()` or `onPause()` use the above code to cycle through the `ViewGroups` and retrieve/store my information?

Comment: I just found out about this method `setRetainInstance()` [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#setRetainInstance%28boolean%29). Do you think this would work?

Comment: It could work. It does have its own drawbacks as well. Especially if your using fragments and flipping between multiples. Plus, it is very resource hungry and will invoke the garbage collector more often (especially in the event of multiple activities/fragments with it activated). The onSaveInstanceState is the most used and safe method. I wouldnt even use it on the onPause, cause it would be redundant. Anytime your activitiy is destoryed, paused, or loses focus, onSaveInstanceState is called

Comment: thank you for the clear explanation. This is still somewhat a problem for me but I think you've put me on the right path.

Comment: Glad I could help, if you need any further help, let me know.